# putting extra hops into traceroute6 on OpenBSD

Tags: routing, openbsd, ipv6, pf, traceroute

I'm running OpenBSD, or maybe FreeBSD.  I don't have lots of IPv4 addresses to waste, but who doesn't have a few billion of IPv6 ones?

How do I add some extra IPv6 hops to a `traceroute6`, around `pf(4)` on OpenBSD?

Similar to [how Ryan Werber of Beagle Networks did it](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/15/star_wars_traceroute/):

```
# traceroute -f2 -m255 -q1 -w2 obiwan.scrye.net
traceroute to obiwan.scrye.net (204.244.252.35), 255 hops max, 40 byte packets
Skipping 1 intermediate hops
 2  hos-tr1.juniper1.rz13.hetzner.de (213.239.224.1)  0.224 ms
 3  core22.hetzner.de (213.239.245.121)  1.115 ms
 4  core1.hetzner.de (213.239.245.177)  4.802 ms
 5  core1.hetzner.de (213.239.245.177)  4.836 ms
 6  juniper1.ffm.hetzner.de (213.239.245.5)  5.366 ms
 7  10gigabitethernet1-4.core1.lon1.he.net (72.52.92.81)  22.797 ms
 8  10gigabitethernet10-4.core1.nyc4.he.net (72.52.92.241)  112.799 ms
 9  10gigabitethernet10-4.core1.nyc4.he.net (72.52.92.241)  148.894 ms
10  100gigabitethernet7-2.core1.chi1.he.net (184.105.223.161)  109.669 ms
11  100ge9-1.core1.sea1.he.net (184.105.223.193)  157.816 ms
12  10ge1-1.core1.yvr1.he.net (184.105.222.2)  176.844 ms
13  10ge1-1.core1.yvr1.he.net (184.105.222.2)  160.813 ms
14  216.218.185.138 (216.218.185.138)  215.201 ms
15  gi4-0-528.bbr3.yyz.epikip.net (206.214.255.9)  152.165 ms
16  216.81.55.118.epikip.net (216.81.55.118)  195.530 ms
17  216.81.55.118.epikip.net (216.81.55.118)  167.154 ms
18  206.214.251.27 (206.214.251.27)  186.840 ms
19  A.NEW.HOPE (206.214.251.6)  208.222 ms
20  It.is.a.period.of.civil.war (206.214.251.9)  171.58 ms
21  It.is.a.period.of.civil.war (206.214.251.9)  184.470 ms
22  Rebel.spaceships (206.214.251.14)  178.100 ms
23  have.won.their.first.victory (206.214.251.22)  158.662 ms
24  against.the.evil.Galactic.Empire (206.214.251.25)  203.261 ms
25  against.the.evil.Galactic.Empire (206.214.251.25)  177.668 ms
26  During.the.battle (206.214.251.30)  172.850 ms
27  to.steal.secret.plans (206.214.251.38)  203.746 ms
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not just something you can do with `pf`. The example you cite mentions using VRFs. On OpenBSD you need to create multiple routing domains (rdomains) using the `rtable` command.

You'll need to build a series of routing tables and virtual interfaces so that each hop jumps to a new table. In order to do the Star Wars crawl you'll also need to either edit your hosts file or set up a name resolver (e.g., bind).

Comment: Which `rtable` command?  There is no such thing on OpenBSD, nor on FreeBSD.